# My modal dialog as a funciton in ts file

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, modal-dialog

Hello my fellow stackoverflowers,

I guess i have a simple question.

In my html i have a Modal Dialog that pops up. It uses ng2 Bootstrap. It works and all but... I want this code

`"<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal()">Login</button>"`

(showModal())

replace it in my ts file as a function

```
showModal(modal: ModalDirective) {

  }
```

How can i do this? i am already struggling more then a hour.

This is my full HTML Code.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal()">Login</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true"> &times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="myForm" role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name' placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
              <label for="uLogin" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password' placeholder="Wachtwoord">
              <label for="uPassword" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

and hits is my full TS code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/common';
import { ModalDirective, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';


class DemoInfo {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

@Component({
  template: require('./template.component.html'),
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ModalDirective],
  viewProviders: [BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS]
})

export class ModalComponent {
  CreateGroup: ControlGroup;
  demoInfo: DemoInfo;
  modal: ModalDirective;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.demoInfo = new DemoInfo();


    this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
      'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.name),
      'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password)
    })
  }
  addNewGroup(demoInfo: DemoInfo) {
    console.log(demoInfo, 'whole object');
    this.demoInfo = new DemoInfo();
  }

  showModal(modal: ModalDirective) {

  }

  hideModal(modal: ModalDirective) {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what i did.

1. I added `@ViewChild('lgModal') modal: any;` in my ModalComponent
2. made a new function called `showModal()`
3. and referenced it by calling `this.modal.dosomething();`